# Start a conversation with a user Botkit

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

I'm using Botkit to create a bot for slack. I was wondering if it was possible to start a conversation using `bot.startConversation()` with a specific user using their user ID or channel ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, you would need to know both the user and channel ids: 
https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/422#issuecomment-250930793